# Method taking reference to an array of references?

Tags: java, arrays, class, methods

I missed one of my lectures in Java, and the subject was classes, methods, constructors etc. The homework is one task:

> Create a class Person, objects of which describe persons, and which
>   contains only two felds: name (String) and year of birth (int). In
>   this class, define
>
> - constructor taking name and year of birth;
> - constructor taking only name and setting the year of birth to default value 1990;
> - method isFemale returning true if this person is a woman (we assume, not very sensibly, that only women and all women have names ending
>     with the letter 'a'); otherwise the method returns false;
> - static function getOlder taking two references to objects of class Person and returning the reference to the older of these two persons;
> - **static function getOldest taking the reference to an array of references to objects of class Person and returning the reference to
>     the oldest person represented in the array;**
> - **static function getYoungestFemale taking the reference to an array of refe- rences to objects of class Person and returning the reference
>     to the youngest woman represented in the array, or null if there is no
>     woman in the array.**
>
> **In a separate class, write a main function in which the whole
>   functionality of the class Person is tested.**

I checked some tutorials and explanations, I didn't go straight here asking for help but after 2 hours of ripping my hair out I've been only able to come up with this:

```
public class Person {
    String name;
    int yob; //year of birth

    public Person() {
        Person jan = new Person("Jan", 1995); //the names are polish
        Person joanna = new Person("Joanna", 1993);
        Person michal = new Person("Michal", 1980);
        Person beata = new Person("Beata", 1979);
        Person kazimierz = new Person("Kazimierz", 1998);
        Person magdalena = new Person("Magdalena", 1999);
    }

    public Person(String name, int yob) {
        this.name = name;
        this.yob = yob;
    }

    public Person(String name) {
        this.name = name;
        this.yob = 1990;
    }

    public static boolean isFemale(String name) {
        if(name.equals("Joanna")) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public static String getOlder(Person x?, Person y?) { // if I understand the task correctly, I should reference any two names?
        if(x?.yob>y?.yob) {
            return x?.name;
        } else {
            return y?.name;
        }

    //getOldest and getYoungestFemale methods go here

    }
}
```

However, I can't wrap my head around the last three steps. My brain is literally boiling. It would really help if anyone could explain the last three bullet points (`getOlder` reference to any 2 people and `getOldest`/`getYoungestFemale`)

If you don't have time to explain, some example of a "method taking a reference to an array" should be enough for me to get a basic understanding.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Put aside the fact that the question deals with instances of `Person`: if you were asked to get the largest `int` from an array, or the smallest even `int`, could you do that?

Comment: You haven't quite got points 3 or 4 yet either. And you almost certainly don't want to be creating those 6 `Person` instances in the default constructor of `Person`.

Comment: @AndyTurner I know how to write "hello, world"-level programs in "public static void main(String[] args)" body, like sorting arrays with loops, finding the max value etc. I just hit a barrier when I suddenly need to use constructors and multiple classes. EDIT: Point 3 just needs replasing "Joanna" with last character check, I can do that later.

Comment: Forget constructors, multiple classes etc. Can you write a method which returns the minimum value in an array of ints? If you can do that, there is no real difference vs finding the oldest Person in an array - you just look through the array for the `Person` with the smallest year of birth.

Comment: @AndyTurner I don't know how to explain this better - this is the most advanced code I wrote ever: pastebin.com/9KDrMzxk

Comment: @Shamanix this is not directly related to the question, but to your default constructor. Has your prof/teacher talked about visibility- and validity-scopes of variables? If so, try to figure out the validity scope of the `Person`s created within the default constructor.

Comment: @Turing85 He didn't, but as I said I missed the last lecture so he might have explained it back then. But I doubt it because he usually lectures in such a weird way that everyone has to learn it themselves anyway.

Comment: @Shamanix Well this is... problematic. Do you know about Heap and Stack memory in Java? That actually IS kind of important for this exercise.

Comment: @Turing85 I heard about it but never "learned it". I started Java classes only a month ago, maybe that explains why I don't know almost anything yet. We only did basic programs like a BMI calculator, selection sorting an array of integers, 2D arrays etc.

Comment: @Shamanix any way I can contact you? At least, for heap/stack I could try and explain it to you without flooding the comment section. I will be in the [chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/) for the next 10 or so minutes.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95628/discussion-between-shamanix-and-turing85).

Answer (score 2):

Here are some hints which should help you work out the answer yourself without me giving away the solution ;)

1)

```
 public static String getOlder(Person x?, Person y?) {
      // if I understand the task correctly, I should reference any two names?     
     if(x?.yob>y?.yob) { 
            return x?.name;       
     } else {         
            return y?.name;       
     }
}
```

This code is almost correct! Just remove the question marks! Also remember that the older person will have an earlier yob. EDIT, also you need to return the reference to the person, not their name, so return either x or y.

2)    `getOldest`  and `getYoungestWoman`

```
Person[]
```

is an array of references to Person objects. You should be able to read up on how to loop through the elements of an array and compare values.

3) an extra: if you declare those 6 Person objects inside the constructor, you won't be able to access them in other methods of the class. it is ok to create the Person objects there, but you must declare them outside the constructor. Declare them  in the class.

Comment: 1) isn't quite type correct. The question states that the method should return the reference to the older person, *not* the name of the older person.

Comment: _Just remove the question marks!_ - I put them there to indicate that I don't know what to write there, of course I wouldn't use them in the final code. So if I remove them, how to I find for example mr. Jan if the reference is x?

Comment: the getOlder method just needs to take 2 person objects. You have called these person x and person y. Inside the method you don't care which person objects they are. To _use_ the method, you create 2 person objects in your `main` method, like `Person person1 = new Person("bob");`, similar for person2, then pass these to the getOlder method like this `getOlder(person1, person2);`

Comment: @KLibby I understand now! Thank you. But I still don't get the array referencing.

Comment: The array is effectively a list of Person objects. Imagine you have  getOldest(Person[] persons) as your method definition. inside the method, persons[0] is the first person in the array. persons[1] is the second person in the array, and so on.

Comment: You can write a loop to go through all the elements in the array, as the method has no way of knowing how long the array will be until it receives it. look up "traversing an array" for examples of how to do this.

Answer (score 2):

Usually.. you don't call it "reference to an array of references of something" You just say "array of something". Even though arrays of objects *are* arrays of references to objects. Just like a variable for an object is just a reference to an object.

```
Type heyImAReference = new ImTheObject();
```

So when you write

```
Person person = new Person();
```

You'll have the class Person as type, `person` as a reference to an instance (or object) of that class and the resulting entity of `new Person()` as the actual thing that is being referenced. Usually called "instance" or in your case "object".

When it comes to arrays of persons and you do

```
Person[] persons = new Person[5];
```

You create via `new Person[5]` an array instance that has 5 slots, in each slot can go a `Person` instance figuratively, actually though you have 5 references. `Person[0]` being the first, `Person[1]` being the second and so on. So that is an "array of references to objects of class Person".

And `persons` is a reference to that. So it is a "reference to an array of references to objects of class Person"

- `static` function `getOldest` taking the reference to an array of references to objects of class Person and returning the reference to the oldest person represented in the array

means nothing more than

```
static Person getOldest(Person[] persons) {
    ...
}
```

I would call that a method that takes an array of Persons and returns a Person. Though technically, it's all just references that go in and come out. The `Person` objects don't "move"

Answer (score 2):

Firstly create another class which will have main method. Within main create an array:

```
Person[] parr = new Person[6];
//Then fill all your person to this array:
parr[0] = new Person("name", year);
parr[1] = ....
```

Then pass this array handler to your methods:

```
Person p1 = Person.findSomething(parr);
```

In Person class:

```
public static Person findSomething(Person[] parr){
  for (Person p : parr){
     if (p.name.endsWith("a")) return p;
  }
  return null;
}
```